# Problem consuming strongly typed datatable (returned from 4.0 webservice) in asp.net 1.1 web application

Tags: asp.net, datatable, asmx

I wrote a webservice in asp.net 4.0 that returns a strongly typed datatable as shown below.
The datatable was created using Visual Studio designer.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]        
public class ConsumerService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
     [WebMethod]
     public ConsumerTable GetConsumer(string key)
     {
      ...
     }

}
```

I've a asp.net 1.1 application where I want to consume ConsumerTable returned by the webmethod. I add service web reference in the asp.net 1.1 application and in the aspx page where I want to use the information, I create instance of the proxy. I do not call the webmethod ... just creat instance of proxy like shown below,

```
public class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{       
    svc.ConsumerService svc = new testProj.svc.ConsumerService();

    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Put user code to initialize the page here
    }

}
```

Everything compiles fine. But as I as I try to execute the code, I get following error.

> The XML element named '' from
>   namespace 'http://tempuri.org' is
>   already present in the current scope.
>   Use XML attributes to specify another
>   XML name or namespace for the element.

I tried use the webmethod in 4.0 web application and everything works as expected. Can anyone please help me with the solution for this error? Is there any better approach to consuming 4.0 typed datatable/dataset in 1.1 applications?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question is to ask why you aren't using at least ASP.NET 2.0? It fixed a lot of XML bugs.

The next question is why you didn't use WCF to create your service? All new web service development on Microsoft platforms should use WCF.

Finally, if the problem occurs even when you don't call any webmethods, then the problem obviously has nothing to do with typed datatables! Try to simplify the problem by creating a simpler web service that only returns `int` or `string` and see what happens.